# Outsourcing Recursive DNS in a Windows Domain Environment

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, dnssec

We've been considering utilizing a third-party recursive DNS provider like OpenDNS (or anyone) to provide a layer of antiphishing and DNSSEC validation (without having to implement those features internally).

To allow internal (Windows domain) DNS to function normally, are these recursive DNS providers typically configured as DNS forwarders in the Windows DNS service?

Are there any other best practices or considerations when outsourcing recursive DNS?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Your externally-facing DNS servers don't do recursion at all (or shouldn't,) and your internal DNS servers probably forward to Google, who already supports DNSSEC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question in a word, "yes".

To answer your second, best practices questions are usually very subjective and don't lend themselves well to the Stack Exchange format. The rule of thumb is that there should be an answer, and it should be the *right* answer, rather than a pool of opinions that you're trying to draw from.

That said, there are two significant caveats to what you are doing, and they are significant enough to where I think it's worth taking a stab at it.

## Know what DNSSEC is actually protecting you from.

Until validating stub resolvers become more widespread in implementation by OS vendors, a reply packet with the `AD` (authenticated data) bit set is basically saying this:

> "I trusted this data, so you can also trust this data! ...If you trust me, **and the network between us**."

Read that very carefully. If your goal is to "[avoid] having to implement those features internally", make sure you understand what you're getting out of DNSSEC. Most people don't. It means that you're more resilient to attacks against the *remote* recursive DNS server, but [you're still completely open to poisoning attacks directed against *your* infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions#Stub_resolvers). The probability of someone specifically targeting you is much lower of course, but assuming that you are not the target only scales as well as how much you have to lose and someone's interest in it.

These risks are significantly reduced if the network path between you and the recursive server performing validation does not cross the internet. That's mutually exclusive to outsourcing it though, shy of the traffic itself actually being encrypted.

Side note: OpenDNS does implement [dnscrypt](https://www.opendns.com/about/innovations/dnscrypt/) if you're interested in leveraging it, but to go that route you'd have to determine that the level of complexity in implementing and supporting it vs. just performing your own DNSSEC validation is worth the cost:benefit ratio.

### You get what you pay for.

This is a universal rule to business IT environments. It should be no surprise that it also applies here. If you're introducing an external dependency to your network infrastructure, what happens when that service goes down? What is your remediation path? Who is going to pay for the damages? If the service is working from the perspective of others but is broken in a narrow way that only impacts your environment, how fast can you expect the remote party to take your opinion seriously and perform a repair (SLA)?

If you're going to create this kind of dependency, make sure you're paying for the service in some way. You are always giving up something by adding an external dependency to your network without a subscription of some sort, and the choice to not do so is weighing your odds on the gamble.

### Full disclosure

I'm a DNS operator for an American MSO. That said, people like me don't really stand to benefit financially from you following this advice. Migrating away from your ISP's DNS cluster is less load on what we manage.

Comment: I completely understand your point regarding the discussion of best practices, which is really why I included the first question so that we could have a fixed answer despite my knowledge that it really did work via forwarders. This is one of those "you don't know what you don't know" subjects, so it is difficult to research best practices and can really only get a good answer from a forum such as this. Your answer did help, and did turn on a couple of light bulbs here, so thank you for your thoughtful response.

Comment: @Beems [SE sites are not forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/206620), but I get what you mean. :) Happy to help, and I usually post at this length if it's stuff I expect to come up again in the future. You're helping us help the internets.

Answer (score -2):

Configure DNS root hints, it reduces your administration and provides better availability on external DNS queries

for Interval queries DNS forwarders works fine